# How to register multiple events on multiple layers with Openlayers

Tags: openlayers-2, events

Is there a way to register multiple events on multiple objects with one command?

In the API doc one can find several solutions(http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Events-js.html#OpenLayers.Events.register), but for me it seems, that the combination of multiple layer and multiple events is not possible.

Conretely I would like to register the loadstart and loadend events on all of my layers which are about 15.

I tried among others:

```
events.on({
    "loadstart": function1,
    "loadend": function2,
    scope: [layer1, layer2, layer3]
    });
```

But it didn't work (it seemed that one cannot start with events.on, the object has to be declared in the front)....